# Convert string into array or list of dicts

Tags: python, arrays, string, dictionary

I am running an API call that gives as output the next string:

```
"[{'hour':'5', 'day':'11', 'month':'sep', 'year':'2019'}, {'user_id':'x651242w', 'session_id':4025, 'location':'USA'}]"
```

I want to access location what should I do in this case ?

I am thinking of converting the string into array of dictionaries or list of dictionaries?

Comment: This wouldn't be a valid list

Comment: so how to convert is from str to list ?

Comment: is the string exactly like tihis? at the end it misses a closing bracket "}"

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` to convert to a list of dicts first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import ast

s = "[{'hour':'5', 'day':'11', 'month':'sep', 'year':'2019'}, {'user_id':'x651242w', 'session_id':4025, 'location':'USA'}]"
lst = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(lst)
# [{'hour': '5', 'day': '11', 'month': 'sep', 'year': '2019'}, {'user_id': 'x651242w', 'session_id': 4025, 'location': 'USA'}]
print(lst[1]['location'])
# USA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "[{'hour':'5', 'day':'11', 'month':'sep', 'year':'2019'}, {'user_id':'x651242w', 'session_id':4025, 'location':'USA'}]"
res = list(eval(s))
print(res[1]["location"])
'USA'
```

Comment: *eval()* is generally frowned upon. Either way, why the call to *list()*?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you don't know which of the dictionaries contains the location key. This might give you some more general ideas too:

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = "[{'hour':'5', 'day':'11', 'month':'sep', 'year':'2019'}, {'user_id':'x651242w', 'session_id':4025, 'location':'USA'}]"

for dict_ in literal_eval(s):
  if location := dict_.get('location'):
    print(location)
```

**Output:**

```
USA
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks json, for json , we have to change single quote to double quote and then you can parse the json:

```
str1 = "[{'hour':'5', 'day':'11', 'month':'sep', 'year':'2019'}, 
         {'user_id':'x651242w', 'session_id':4025, 'location':'USA'}]"
json_str = str1.replace("'", '"')
json_format = json.loads(a)
json_format[1]["location"]
```